# Bash script to pull variable credentials from another file using ". filename"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running Ubuntu 18.04 subsystem on Windows 10, but have also tried to do this on a Ubuntu 18.04 Google cloud virtual machine.

I've realised that baking my login credentials into my scripts is a rather dumb idea, not just for the security risks but because I'll have to edit every script if I change my password...

I discovered that I should be able to have a file that contains my credentials and put them "inline" when I run my script by using ". file", however when I run my script it just returns an error that the file isn't found.

Using `ls` on the directory I run the script from contains:

- test.sh
- credential

### "credential" file contents

```
USER=<username>
PWD=<password>
```

### Current script for test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

DS=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "11 days ago")
DE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "1 day ago")

. credential

rm -f cookiejar

curl  /dev/null -s -S -L -f -c cookiejar 'https://url/auth/authenticate' -d name=$USER -d passwd=$PWD
```

### Error Message

```
+ set -eu
+ date +%Y-%m-%d -d 11 days ago
+ DS=2020-01-05
+ date +%Y-%m-%d -d 1 day ago
+ DE=2020-01-15
+ account=465
+ . credential test.sh: 9: .: credential: not found
```

I've tried messing around with the spaces between the ". credential" line of the script and tried to find out what I might be doing wrong online but haven't been able to google search correctly to find a relevant answer.

Can someone confirm what I'm missing/ not aware of here or point me to documentation that might help? This is my first time trying to do something like this so apologies if this is a basic question.

Comment: You could check if a .netrc works for you

Comment: Basic check: are you running your script from the same folder where your `credential` file is located?

Comment: What is the current directory when you run `test.sh`? What is the exact command you use to run it? In which directory is `credential`. Please [edit] your question to add this information, don't answer in a comment.

Comment: @Poshi yes, I'm running the `credential file` in the same folder as the `test.sh` script.

Comment: @El_Birdo Don't write additional information or clarification in comments. [edit] your question instead.

Comment: @Marged I'd like to avoid putting these in the .netrc file as I've currently got all client server logins stored there. The objective later down the line is to find common parts of scripts and create `ref files` for these parts that are then brought inline. So instead of writing the same code over again, my scripts will just pull them in with 1 line.

Comment: Note that `. filename` searches for `filename` in `PATH`. If `PATH` does not contain `.`, it will not find `filename` in the current directory. You might have to use something like `. ./filename` or `. $(dirname $0)/filename` depending on whether you have `filename` in the current working directory or in the same directory as the calling script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` uses path lookup to find the file named by its argument. Since the current working directory typically is not in your `PATH` (nor should it), `.` won't find the file. Instead, use

```
. ./credential
```

to bypass `PATH` lookup.

This isn't really safe, though, because now you are restricted to running the script from the proper directory. Either put `credential` *in* a directory on your `PATH`, or use an absolute path to specify where `credential` is located.

Comment: If `credential` is expected to be in the same directory as the calling script, you could use `. $(dirname $0)/credential`.

Comment: ... Except you should quote it for robustness: `. "$(dirname "$0")"/credential`